# What's the ideal usage for italics for names?

Tags: style

I write articles on a website about anime, manga, cosplay, etc. I want to know whether I should italicise the names of anime or not.

In some articles, I have to put the name of a certain anime too many times. It looks bad with so much italics...

So my question is: **What's the ideal usage of italics concerning names?**

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't. I think it would distract the reader too much.

Comment: Whatever you decide to do, just be consistent. Lauren's answer is a good one, or you can consult any number of style guides. (*The Yahoo Style Guide* is great for web work.)

Comment: @NoviceWriterFance - Not setting off titles of works in quotes or italics can be very confusing to readers, particularly those not familiar with the works in question.

Comment: Names of what -- series? Episodes?  (Is that the right word?)  Characters?

Comment: Oh, names of anime shows, it's like a TV show, or an enhanced version of cartoons, or Japanese animation you can say.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rule of thumb about italics vs. quotes is "big things get italics, little things (or pieces of big things) get quotes."

If it's the name of a book or magazine, italicize it.

If it's the name of an article or blog post, put it in quotes.

If it's the name of a movie, italicize it.

TV shows have become debatable, because they are getting "bigger" in the sense of being longer and becoming more important. So I think you'd have to consider the context.

- If you talk about TV shows and movies in the same piece, use quotes
  for the TV show. (Basil Rathbone in *The Hound of the Baskervilles* vs. Benedict Cumberbatch in the BBC's "Sherlock")
- If you are only talking about various TV shows, use italics. (Benedict Cumberbatch in the BBC's *Sherlock* vs. Jonny Lee Miller in CBS's *Elementary*)
- If you are talking about a TV show as a whole *and* the names of
  various episodes, use italics for the show name and quotes for the
  episode names. (*Sherlock*'s Season 3 was "The Empty Hearse," "The Sign of Three," and "His Last Vow")

If it looks silly that you're italicizing the name so many times, maybe you need to edit the piece so you aren't saying the name so much.

**ETA at Neil's request** While this may seem contrary, I would say that a series of books which has a formal title doesn't get formatting at all: the Lord of the Rings trilogy, the Last Herald-Mage trilogy, the Belgariad, the Malloreon, the Dragonriders of Pern series. My instinct is that each of these is a name for a collection of things, an umbrella term, rather than a proper name.

Comment: Great answer. To clarify: Would a series of books be placed in italics or between apostrophes?

Comment: @NeilFein Apostrophes? Do you mean quotes?

Comment: Whoops. Yes, quotation marks.